# Wondering where to house api call logic. inside the Container or Component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a container that passes props and an apiCall action to a component which will mainly just render the result of that call. My question is should I leave the invoking of that action up to the component or move it out into the container and just pass the array of items to the component?

Here is my container code. The fetchShowingsListShowings is the one in question. Also, I will be renaming that soon enough so bear with me.

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/showingsListActions';
import ShowingsList from '../components/ShowingsList';

const ShowingsListContainer = (props) => {
  return (
    <ShowingsList
        isLoading={props.isLoading}
        showings={props.showings}
        fetchShowingsListShowings={props.actions.fetchShowingsListShowings}
    />
  );
};

ShowingsListContainer.propTypes = {
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  showings: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoading: state.showingsList.isLoading,
    showings: state.showingsList.showings
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ShowingsListContainer);
```

And my component. Which calls the API action on componentWillMount.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ShowingsListItem from './ShowingsListItem';

class ShowingsList extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchShowingsListShowings();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.props.isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> :
      <ul className="list-unstyled">
        {this.props.showings.map((showing,index) => <ShowingsListItem showing={showing} key={'showing' + index}/>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ShowingsList.propTypes = {
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  showings: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  fetchShowingsListShowings: PropTypes.func.isRequired   
 };

export default ShowingsList;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in React with Redux the term 'Container' just means a component that is connected to the Store, essentially whatever you use the react-redux 'connect' method with. Your ShowingsList can be a 'dumb' (or functional) component meaning it's just a component that takes in data and displays content. The general 'best' practice is to have your dumb components just be concerned with presentation, and your container components handle all the logic interacting with the Redux Store. If you follow this logic, fetch the data in the container, and pass the data to the nested component. That being said, it'll work either way so you don't really need to change anything if you're happy with it now.

To follow this pattern do something like this:

1. modify your Container component to be an ES6 class `extends React.Component`.. and optionally change your ShowingsList to be a functional component (like your ShowingsList is now)
2. put a componentWillMount in your Container and put the API call there.
3. pass the list to the presentational component.

Here's an article written by Dan Abramov, the author of Redux on this very topic.
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.g695y2gwd

Comment: Got it, I originally had it that way but wasn't quite sure what best practices were so I flip flopped. Thanks for the quick reply.